# mathpazo stopped working

Tags: fonts, mactex, mathpazo, math-fonts

I recently installed the latest MacTex (2017) on my laptop, then mathpazo stopped working -- it is not showing the correct font. I copy-paste the exact same file onto Overleaf, the font is showing just fine. Does any one know whether there is a conflict between new MacTex distribution and mathpazo? Thanks!

Comment: Make a minimal example and show it along with its log-file.

Comment: How do you know it's the wrong font?

Comment: Also, what OS version are you using?

Comment: thank you all. I finally located the problem. It turns out mathpazo is not compatible with pstricks in the new MacTex 2017 -- if deactivate pstricks then mathepazo works again.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I finally located the problem (by deactivating other packages in use one by one while keeping `\usepackage[sc, osf]{mathpazo}`  active). It turns out `mathpazo` is incompatible with `\usepackage{pstricks,pst-tree,pstricks-add}` in MacTex 2017.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer. I tried a minimal example with `\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}` and `\usepackage{pstricks,pst-tree,pstricks-add}`, with no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Do you use MacTex 2017? In any case, as I said, this was a fix to my particular case. In fact, I tested the exact same tex file with both \usepackage{pstricks,pst-tree,pstricks-add} and \usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo} active on Overleaf, and it worked just fine. It just doesn't work on my local laptop -- it finally worked once I deactivated \usepackage{pstricks,pst-tree,pstricks-add}

Comment: Of course I use MacTeX 2017, otherwise I'd not comment. Is adding a minimal example too difficult?